# Sending data ajax to php, not refreshing whole page, but execute php again in the same file

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have made index.php page with buttons that generate tables. PHP code/script bellow is generated after clicking these buttons.

> All parts of code that you can see here are in admin.php file but visible in index.php.

I have generated table with php with mysql data. I also generated **IDs for buttons that should be used for deleting a table row without refreshing the whole view**.

I have JQuery function with JQuery + Ajax that is triggered after pressing one of the buttons for deletion.

```
    $(".delete-but").click(function() { 
      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this table row?")){
        var butId = $(this).attr('id');         
        $.ajax({
                  type: "post",
                  data: {
                            action: 'expo', 
                            deletion: 'butId'
                  },
                  success: function(result) {
                    content.html(result);                       
        }});
      }
      else{
        return false;
      } 

    });
```

Code for generating part of the table with buttons:

```
    $data .="<td>"."<button id=".$row[id_expozice]."class='delete-but'><form action='admin_script.php.php' method='post'>Delete</button>"."</td>";
```

I have general *button* argument in top of JQuery function. If I press a button for deletion, *confirm* panel pop up, then I press OK and I am able to send an alert to page if I want. I am passing an ID value for clicked button for deletion, that I wanna get back to php used as a sign to delete row in a table, to JQuery function (butId). **I want to use Ajax to send butId back to php and run php script again to delete row in Mysql**.

I echoed:

- echo "I am here";          Where I am.
- echo "I want to be here";  Where I want to be.

  ```
  //echo $_SESSION["user"];       
  if(isset($_POST['action'])){
      $data = '';

      //expo      

      if($_POST['action'] == "expo") {
          $sql = "SELECT id_expozice, jmeno, id_zamestnance, typ_expozice, trvani_od, trvani_do, id_pronajimatel FROM Expozice";
          $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

          echo "I am here";

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              if(isset ($_POST['deletion'])){                 

                  if ($_POST['deletion'] == $row.[id_expozice]){

                      echo " I want to be here "; //to delete row table and mysql.

                  }
              }
            else{
              $data .= "<tr>";
              $data .="<td>".$row[id_expozice]."</td>";
              $data .="<td>".$row[jmeno]."</td>";             
              $data .="<td>".$row[typ_expozice]."</td>";
              $data .="<td>".$row[trvani_od]."</td>";
              $data .="<td>".$row[trvani_do]."</td>"; 
              $data .="<td>".$row[id_pronajimatel]."</td>";
              $data .="<td>".$row[id_zamestnance]."</td>";
              $data .="<td>"."<button id=".$row[id_expozice]." class='delete-but'><form action='admin_script.php.php' method='post';'>Delete</button>"."</td>";
              $data .="</tr>";
            }
          }           
          $final_data = '<table><thead><tr><td> Exposition ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Type</td>
          <td>Duration from</td><td>Duration to</td><td>Lessor ID</td><td>Employee ID</td><td>Delete</td></tr></thead><tbody>'.$data.'</tbody></table>';
          echo $final_data;
      }
  ```

  **How could I set Ajax to send butId back to php and run php script again?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `.` where it should not be.  Change this line

```
if ($_POST['deletion'] == $row.['id_expozice']){
```

To

```
if ($_POST['deletion'] == $row['id_expozice']){
```

You also don't have any of your row objects in quotes.

```
 $.ajax({
              type: "post",
              URL: "admin.php",
              data: {
                        action: 'expo', 
                        deletion: 'butId'
              },
              success: function(result) {
                content.html(result);                       
    }});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't even go through `if(isset ($_POST['deletion']))` condition

Comment: @AzurPazur are you sure the query is actually returning any rows?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup. Yes. I just need to know how change the ajax data .success() function

Comment: If I understand correctly, you'll just do another AJAX function nested in the success callback.

Comment: @AzurPazur I now understand your problem.  You haven't set the URL for the AJAX call.  See my edit to my answer for the correct way.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Thank you for your effort. But I am already on admin.php so I don't need to set url. I dit it - without effect.

I am not sure if `success: function(result) {content.html(result);  }` is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try adding dataType: 'json' to your ajax call lets see the result

```
     $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      data: {
      action: 'expo',
      deletion: 'butId'
      },
      dataType:"json",
              success: function(result) {
                content.html(result);                       
    }});
```